# trying to code an inside server joke but aint working how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so there is an inside joke in my server where someone said 9 + 2 = 12, so im coding my bot so when someone says `,cal 9 + 2` the bot shows an embed which says calculator as title, and a answer of 12, which works well, but any other calculations wont work, here is the code:

```
const Math = require("mathjs");

module.exports = {
    name: "cal",
    description: "Calculates something",

    async execute (Client, message, args, Discord){
        const lol = '12'
        const LOL = '9 + 2'

        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a question to solve");

        let resp;

        try{
            resp = Math.evaluate(args.join(" "))
        } catch (e) {
            return message.channel.send("Please provide a **valid** question to answer")
        }
        if(args[0] = '9+2' || '9 + 2' || '9+ 2' || '9 +2'){
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("Calculator")
            .addField("Question", `\`\`\`css\n${LOL}\`\`\``)
            .addField("Answer", `\`\`\`css\n${lol}\`\`\``)

            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
        else{
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("Calculator")
            .addField("Question", `\`\`\`css\n${args.join(" ")}\`\`\``)
            .addField("Answer", `\`\`\`css\n${resp}\`\`\``)

            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
}
```

the script without the if function, the math part works perfectly! but the joke aint there.

Comment: You are probably going to need some form of parser. This [COMPUTERPHILE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDtZLm7HIJs&ab_channel=Computerphile) video by [Graham Hutton](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

> `if(args[0] = '9+2' || '9 + 2' || '9+ 2' || '9 +2'){`

First of all, `=` is used only for assignments, such as `const foo = 'bar'`. For comparison, use the triple equals, such as `'foo' === 'foo'`.

Second of all, `x === y || z` does not actually do what you think it does. Statements on both sides of the logical OR operator (`||`) will always be evaluated completely separately. The above will not mean, "`x` equals either `y` or `z`" but instead, "`x` equals `y`, or `z` is truthy"

```js
// this means that something like this
// will always return truthy.
// if you separate the two statements, 
// the second will always be truthy because
// a string, by itself, *is* truthy

if (true === false || 'hello') {
  console.log('It passed');
};
```

Instead of `x === y || z`, you'll have to take the more verbose option, which is:

```js
x === y || x === z /* ... */
```

Or, you could use `Array#includes()`, and put all of the valid strings in an array:

```js
// x === y || x === z
[y, z].includes(x);
```

For your situation, however, I think the best option would be to use `RegExp#test()`, with a regex such as: `^9\s*\+\s*2$`:

```js
if (/^9\s*\+\s*2$/.test(message.content)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: can u add the whole if function so i can see what you did?

Comment: Just replace `if(args[0] = '9+2' || '9 + 2' || '9+ 2' || '9 +2'){` with one of the options I described

Comment: saddly i tried everyone of them, but none of them work, it only works when i do 9+2 together, any other ways of doing it like 9 + 2 does not work

Comment: That would be because you're only comparing `args[0]`. If you do `9 + 2`, it will be `9`. If you do `9+ 2`, it will be `9+`. You need to edit your code to account for that (for example, using `args.join(' ')`

Comment: so something like this? ```if (args.join(' ')[0] == "9 + 2" || args.join(' ')[0] == "9+2" || args.join(' ')[0] == "9 +2" || args.join(' ')[0] == "9+ 2") {```

Comment: Probably, but without the `[0]`, as that says you are trying to access an index in the variable, when it is a string, because you just joined it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (I don't know if it will work though...):

```
    const hi = [ ',cal 9+12', ',cal 9 +12', ',cal 9+ 12']
    if(hi.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
  

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("Calculator")
            .addField("Question", `\`\`\`css\n${LOL}\`\`\``)
            .addField("Answer", `\`\`\`css\n${lol}\`\`\``)

            return message.channel.send(embed)

    }
```

I know there are so many ways this could be done better but here is mine.